# how to do 'cut' with electron-localshortcut

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to use keyboard shortcuts in mac without using menu.

I read this.

[Can I make non global accelerators without putting things in a menu?](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1334)

And now I know that I can use this module.

[electron-localshortcut](https://github.com/parro-it/electron-localshortcut)

But how can I use copy, cut, and paste?

```
localShortcut.register(mainWindow, 'CmdOrCtrl+X', () => {
  app.cut()
})
```

Ofcourse you can't write like this.

There is no cut method in app.

Someone, please help me.

Maybe, I can send to renderer process and do something like document.execCommand('copy') on renderer process but it's too bother...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One best way is using `keydown` and `keyup` events or you can just use electron web-contents `before-input-event` event which is emitted before dispatching `keydown` and `keyup` events in the page. It can be used to catch and handle custom shortcuts that are not visible in the menu. you can check the combination of key you want to add shortcut and then add a callback.
2. If you don't want to do manual shortcut parsing there are libraries that do advanced key detection such as [mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap).

Comment: Thank you. But how "It can be used to catch and handle custom shortcuts that are not visible in the menu" is possible? You can "catch" shortcuts but how do you "handle" them? I mean ofcourse you can use something like remote.clipboard.writeText but it is too bother.  I want to know how do you handle cut or copy.

Comment: This is one other way you can  simply add your own callback
 contents.on('before-input-event', (event, input) => {
        if (input.control && input.key === 'c') {
          event.preventDefault();
          yourOwnCustomCallback();
        }
      });
For cut and copy you can use clipboard or webcontents cut and copy methods please go with electron webContents documentation once